# How to use Visual Studio Code on an Android device?

Tags: applications, development

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 and it has cool features to replace laptops, but it is unfortunately running Android OS, and not many development apps are available for Android.

Is there an option to run VS Code at least on an Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two ways to use Linux on Android so we can use VS Code :**

- First *easy way* (Virtual Network Computing) (VNC):

  **1. Install a Linux distro via "Termux"**

  `pkg update -y && pkg install proot wget tar pulseaudio  -y &&  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndronixApp/AndronixOrigin/master/Rootfs/Ubuntu19/ubuntu19.sh && chmod +x ubuntu19.sh && ./ubuntu19.sh`

  **2. Install Linux GUI desktop environment like "Xfce".**

  sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies -y

  **3. start a VNC server on your linux.**

  sudo apt-get install tightvncserver -y

  **4. Open ["VNC Viewer"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android&hl=en) on android to start hacking.**

  you may need to do command `vncserver -list` to list the port

  **5. Install [vscode for ARM64](https://code.headmelted.com/)**

  **6. Optional: Install NodeJS for ARM64.**

  `apt install nodejs`

---

- Second hacky way (Linux Natively):

more info:

https://medium.com/@quantvc/running-debian-on-android-device-natively-73545c9b0757

Helpful Resources:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android

List of some ARM64 Hackers:

@Lemon1I @boby2001820 @NTAuthority @gus33000

Worth mentioning:

https://github.com/WOA-Project

Comment: The question was not to use but to run VS Code on Android.

Comment: Is there another way to run vscode on android device?

Comment: That worth mentioning link is for advertisement or somehow related to the question or answer?

Comment: Related to ARM64 hackers and projects

Answer (score 2):

The open-source version of VS Code is called [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server). To run it on Android (without root) you will need:

[Termux from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/) as changes to the Google Play Store policies are no longer compatible with Termux releases.

**2023 Update**

For an easier install use the Termux-User-Repository

From: https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues/5745

> pkg install tur-repo
>
> pkg install code-server

**Old Instructions**

Once running Termux you will need to install a bunch of packages as `code-server` is an [Electron app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) and needs support from `nodejs`.

```
pkg install nodejs

pkg install yarn
```

Per the [Termux NodeJS wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/index.php?title=Node.js) you should probably have installed:

```
pkg install build-essential

pkg install python
```

As they are needed for building native extensions.

And finally install `code-server` itself.

```
yarn global add code-server
```

**warning installing `code-server` takes a while**

`code-server` is now installed and will be the back-end for your front-end which will be a Chromium based browser, like Chrome for Android or Microsoft Edge.

```
code-server
```

You'll probably want to run the server in the background like `code-server &`. The ampersand puts the process in the background.

At that point you'll get some logs about where to find the password.

Open up a browser, as I was using Samsung DeX I used Samsung Internet, connect to `127.0.0.1:8080` and enter password.

In my case I used `cat ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml` to find out what was configured.

[image: VSCode using Samsung Browser with Termux on Android]

As you can see in the screenshot, even the MS Python plugin seems to work (for now).

**A Few Caveats**

- [`code-server` is not Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/v3.5.0/doc/FAQ.md#differences-compared-to-vs-code) The summary is that not all plugins are supported, YMMV.
- I'm using Termux and code-server with Samsung DeX so I don't have any keyboard issues that others have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code does not yet exist for Android, so there's no way to run it for now. There are some other good editors though, such as [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/apps#android) that you may be able to use in the meantime.