# How can I get a ubuntu desktop on my Galaxy S8 Ultra?

Tags: linux, termux

I have installed UserLand and selected Ubuntu but all I see is this (note that I am in DEX mode on a Galaxy S8 Ultra):
[image]

All the tutorials say I have to set a VNC username and password but it never prompts me to do that. Any ideas?

FYI ultimately I want to run vscode and docker in the ubuntu instance.

Comment: If you just want VSCode in Termux see [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230010/3573). If you want to run Docker on your Samsung S8 you'll need to root the phone and follow [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234575/3573)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I use dev containers with vscode so it's a little complicated. Am I able to run a full Ubuntu desktop VM?

Comment: You should probably explain in more detail what you want to accomplish. Realize that distro desktops are just additional load, but your image already shows a desktop. Also clearly state the make/model/OS version of your device as recent Android OS versions have put limitations.

Comment: Does Linux Deploy not work?

Answer (score 1):

Install Termux and VNC Viewer. Open Termux and run these commands:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
pkg install root-repo x11-repo
pkg install proot proot-distro
termux-setup-storage
proot-disto install ubuntu
proot-distro login ubuntu
```

In Ubuntu shell:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install sudo nano
adduser name #replace name with any username
exit
```

In Termux:

```
proot-distro login --user name ubuntu
```

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server
vncserver
vncserver -kill :1
nano .vnc/xstartup
```

Edit `xstartup` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
startxfce4
```

Press Ctrl+O and Enter, then Ctrl+X.

```
chmod +777 .vnc/xstartup
vncserver -geometry 1280x720 #replace 1280x720 with your resolution
```

Don't close Termux, open VNC Viewer, tap `+`, set address `localhost:1`. Save connection and enter it. Now you have Ubuntu desktop.