# How to resolve cannot stat /data/dalvik-cache when installing ubuntu via termux

Tags: linux, termux

I am trying to follow the suggestions in the answer to this question ([How can I get a ubuntu desktop on my Galaxy S8 Ultra?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248446/how-can-i-get-a-ubuntu-desktop-on-my-galaxy-s8-ultra)) in order to be able  to run vscode and ubuntu on my samsung galaxy s8+ tablet. I have installed ubuntu via termux and proot-distro but when I try and open an ubuntu shell it says:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
pkg install root-repo x11-repo
pkg install proot proot-distro
termux-setup-storage
proot-disto install ubuntu
proot-distro login ubuntu
```

and I get

```
stat: cannot stat '/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
```

I have found this answer (https://groups.google.com/g/android-porting/c/4VrxsM1pLso) indicating that some directory write access has not been granted somewhere but I do not know how to even begin to deal with this issue. any advice would be appreciated! My model number is Galaxy Tab S8+ 5G SM-x806B.